# how to add function inside select query

Tags: c#, linq, function, select

```
select new FeedResource
{ 
   Title = (string)details.Element("title"),  
   Host = (string)details.Element("link"),   
   Description = (string)details.Element("description"), 
   PublishedOn = (DateTime?)details.Element("pubDate"), 
   Generator = (string)details.Element("generator"),  
  Language = (string)details.Element("language")
}
```

In the above code i want to pass the type cast value  to another function,
Example

```
Description = getValidDescription((string) details.Element("description"))
```

but i am not able to achieve, any inputs?

Note : The type casting is required to handle null values (that is in case no value present for "description" it (XElement) handles null perfectly.

Comment: try write the getValidDescription(string) method, everything else seems OK

Comment: As itowlson asked, what is the error. Because there shouldn't be an issue with calling another method the way you want. Perhaps you should also include your getValidDescription method (or at the very least the signature). Help us help you...

Comment: apologises. it is working the problem is with lot of parameters passed to same method, which raised the exception. (one of them does have (string) type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine for me; what is the error message? Example:

```
// doesn't have to be static - just simpler for my test
static string getValidDescription(string description)
{
    // handle nulls safely (could return a default here)
    if (description == null) return null;
    // for example only...
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
        .ToTitleCase(description);
}

var qry =
    from details in doc.Root.Elements("detail")
    select new FeedResource
    {
        Title = (string)details.Element("title"),
        Host = (string)details.Element("link"),
        Description = getValidDescription((string) details.Element("description")),
        PublishedOn = (DateTime?)details.Element("pubDate"),
        Generator = (string)details.Element("generator"),
        Language = (string)details.Element("language")
    };
```